# OpenXML Get Sheet by Name VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, openxml

Everything I've seen is written in C#. Unfortunately all my legacy code is written .Net and I don't have the luxury of rewriting all of my code. I am trying to use OpenXML to read a specific sheet in an Excel workbook. The following code works in C#:

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(Dts.Variables["stFlatFileConnString"].Value.ToString(), false))
            {
                WorkbookPart bkPart = doc.WorkbookPart;
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook workbook = bkPart.Workbook;
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet s = workbook.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Where(sht => sht.Name == "COMMON").FirstOrDefault();
                .....
            }
```

I've tried converting it to VB.Net but I can't get the descendants line to work. The "sht" is erroring as "not declared". In the C# code, I didn't have to declare it. :

```
        Using spreadsheetDocument As SpreadsheetDocument = spreadsheetDocument.Open(Dts.Variables("stFlatFileConnString").Value.ToString(), False)
             Dim bkPart As WorkbookPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart
             Dim bkworkbook As Workbook = bkPart.Workbook
             Dim Sheets As Sheet = bkworkbook.Descendants(Of Sheet)().Where(sht >= sht.Name = "COMMON").FirstOrDefault()
             ......
       End Using
```

How do I need to format the line so I can open a specific sheet in VB.Net?

Comment: The syntax in VB.NET is `.Where(Function(sht) sht.Name = "COMMON")`

Comment: Thanks - that was it. I wish this was more apparent from Microsoft's documentation.